# For a sequence with an infinite number of $1$'s to converge to something other than $1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I understand (roughly) why a sequence with an infinite number of $1$'s to converge to something other than $1$ is impossible, but I cannot find what is wrong with the my reasoning below.

Define $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=1$ if $x\leq 0$ and $f(x)=-1$ otherwise. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable, we can find a function $g:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ that takes every natural number to an output of $f$.

$g$ can thus define a sequence with an infinite number of $1$'s that converges to $-1$.

Comment: And *why* does $g$ converge to $-1$?

Comment: I don't understand the last line.  Why does this sequence have   infinitely many $1$'s?  Why does it converge to $-1$?

Comment: This sequence doesn't converge at all, as it has infinitely many $1$s and $-1$s.

Comment: I see. I thought an infinite number of $1$'s would precede an infinite number $-1$'s in $g$. I guess you either cannot define it that way or guarantee it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you mean that $g \circ f:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ will converge to $-1$. That is not true, because $g$ will "mix" your original sequence, reordering the terms and affecting the convergence. If I reorder an infinite numbers of terms in a sequence, it may not converge.

Comment: And I suppose you cannot have an infinite number of $1$'s that would precede an infinite number $-1$'s in $g$?

Comment: And if OP is relying on lim g∘f = g(lim f), that works only if g is continuous.